# Implementing a switch/command like -h

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

It seems like it is possible to create optional arguments with argparse that "override" otherwise required arguments (be it positional or required options).

A example would be the --help/-h switch, which just displays the help and exit. Now I need to implement behaviour exactly like this ; I need a switch/option that can be used without using any of the otherwise required arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how the 'help' switch is implemented:

```
           self.add_argument(
               default_prefix+'h', default_prefix*2+'help',
               action='help', default=SUPPRESS,
               help=_('show this help message and exit'))
```

You need to provide an action that short circuits argument processing; the `'help'` action does this by exiting the program.

Comment: Subclassing argparse.Action and supplying a `__call__` method which calls `sys.exit` works just fine. Adding `nargs=0` to `add_argument` makes it act as a switch. Thanks!